# 301 redirect works great, Except on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, redirect, hyperlink, http-status-code-301

Doing a 301-redirect using a PHP redirect for the homepage and an HTML refresh for other pages:

Example of my HTML redirect for a page:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://northernarchitecturalsystems.com/projects_product.html">
```

and using this PHP for homepage:

```
<?php
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
Header( "Location: http://www.northernarchitecturalsystems.com" );
exit(0);
?>
```

I'm permanently moving http://northernbuildingproducts.com/ to http://northernarchitecturalsystems.com

Like I said in the title, everything looks and works great. Except when you use an iPad. I am testing other tablets but I am stumped. I've tried to use the htaccess, php, & html refresh. All work well on desktop and phone but the images break when using an iPad. Not a clue?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you know the images breaking is related to this redirection?

Comment: Because if you type in the URL(www.northernarchitecturalsystems.com) on the iPad the images show up fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm this happens on ipad (as of Nov. 2020), and the problem is common to both Chrome and Safari. When an ipad gets a 301, it basically throws away all the headers from the original request, and fires off the followup request with a fixed set of default headers (e.g. "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate"). We were having problems because a missing slash typo on a URI triggered a 301 response, and ipads were sending these BS headers in the followup request.

Since this is six years old I'm thinking it's a security thing and not considered to be a bug.